# ValueError: n_components=256 must be between 0 and min(n_samples, n_features)=11 with svd_solver='full'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I followed this example and it works very well

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
N = 10
X = iris.data[:N, :2]  
pca1 = PCA(n_components=1)
X_low = pca1.fit_transform(X)
```

Below is my code.

```
results = []
for t in token:
    _, model_out = model(**t)
    results.append(model_out.tolist())


r1 = np.array(results)

r2 = r1.reshape(-1,768)

r2.shape
```

> (11, 768)

```
p2 = PCA(n_components=256).fit_transform(r2)
```

> ValueError: n_components=256 must be between 0 and min(n_samples, n_features)=11 with svd_solver='full'

The dimensions of the array in the example and my code are the same.
I don't know why the error occurs.

Comment: Was the error unclear? n_components should be in between 0 to 11.

Comment: @AniketBote I want to reduce the 768 dimensions to 256 dimensions.

Comment: You need to have samples more than 256 for it too work

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?